# How to clear a plot with a pushButton in PyQt?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, matplotlib-widget

I have created a little GUI in PyQt using QT Designer. I have one button."Clear" button must clear this plot(My clear button calls pushButton). I try to write some code but it don't run. How can I create this clear button? Thank you.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic


form_class = uic.loadUiType("gugus.ui")[0]  # Load the UI


class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):

def __init__(self, parent=None):

    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_pgb)
    self.matplotlibwidget.axes.plot([0, 1, 1.5, 3], [50, 1, 2, 0])

def btn_pgb(self):  

    # Her I should clear my plot, but don`t know how `enter code here`
    self.progressBar.setValue(69)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = MyWindowClass()
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the axes, use `axes.clear()`. To clear the complete figure, use `axes.figure.clear()`.

In your case this would be

```
self.matplotlibwidget.axes.clear()
```

or

```
self.matplotlibwidget.axes.figure.clear()
```

After that you would need to redraw the canvas.

```
self.matplotlibwidget.axes.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot test it, since I don't have a [mcve] available. I forgot to mention that for this to be visible, you'd need to redraw the canvas. See updated answer.

Comment: If this solves the issue, consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), such that it will not stay unsolved forever.